# Regarding Visualforce Page and customization

Tags: visualforce, profile, controller-extension

I have created the Visualforce Page ,if that page is Viewed by Particular user,their count and name should be recorded in the record of custom object,for every user count is different,is it possible to create the picklist value should be dependent on user?

For example sys admin user Viewing page, the count should be displayed as 1 and portal user Viewing the page the count should be displayed as 1 and next time sys admin user viewing the page the count should be 2,like that so on

Apex class:

```
    public class DisplayPage {
    public string CurrentRecordID {get;set;}
    public  list<Page_View__c> viewList {get;set;}
    public static string CurrentRecordID1 {get;set;}

   public DisplayPage(ApexPages.StandardController Controller) {
   }
    public static void TotalRecordUpdate() {

        List <  Page_View__c > totalupdate = new List < Page_View__c > ();
        List <  Page_View__c > recDetails = [select id, Count__c from   Page_View__c where id ='a0L28000003YzNx'];
        system.debug(recDetails);
        for (Page_View__c updateCount: recDetails)
        {
          updateCount.Count__c = updateCount.Count__c++ == NULL ? 1 : updateCount.Count__c++;
           updateCount.AddsName_c__c= userinfo.getusername();

            totalUpdate.add(updateCount);
            system.debug(totalUpdate);
        }
        update totalUpdate;
    }
}
```

Vf Page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showheader="false" StandardController="Page_View__c" extensions="DisplayPage" action="{!TotalRecordUpdate}">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form />
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the Profile of the current user using the `{!$Profile.Id}` and `{!$Profile.Name}` in your Visualforce page.

Regarding the User information, you can use the `{!User.Id}` for example. For more info about the available User fields  follow the link to official documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm

The above two global variables are usable within your Visualforce page. If you need to access user information within your controller (which I think you do), you can use `UserInfo` [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm), specificaly the `UserInfo.getProfileId()` and `UserInfo.getUserId()`.

I think that with these tools you can obtain the required information to pretty easily implement you requirement.

**UPDATE**

If I understood you correctly, you need to update the record for specific profile only, and not update the same `Page_View__c` record all the time. In your current code you are basically keeping a count of `ALL` of your page views, independent of the profile. Your code should be like this:

**Controller**

```
public class DisplayPage {   
   public Integer ViewCount {get; set;}


    public DisplayPage(ApexPages.StandardController Controller) {
        this.ViewCount = 0;
        updateViewCount();  
    }

    public void updateViewCount(){
        Id profileId = UserInfo.getProfileId();
        List<Page_View__c> pageViews = [SELECT Id, Count__c FROM Page_View__c WHERE Profile_Id__c = :profileId ];

        if(pageViews.size() == 0){
           Page_View__c pageView = new Page_View__c(Count__c = 1, Profile_Id__c = profileId);
           insert pageView;
           this.ViewCount = 1;
        }else{
           pageViews[0].Count__c += 1;
           update pageViews[0];
           this.ViewCount = pageViews[0].Count__c;            
        }
    }
}
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showheader="false" StandardController="Page_View__c" extensions="DisplayPage">
    Total view count for profile {!$Profile.Name} is {!ViewCount}
</apex:page>
```

I haven't compiled this code anywhere, I just wrote it here, but I believe it should work. Let me know!

Comment: I am getting the username like userinfo.getusername();depending the user name another picklist field called count is controllable,for example sys admin user the count as 2,portal user as 1,is it possible

Comment: for particular organization there are 10 users are there?the code should have to work

Comment: I am sending my code both vf page and controller class,please alter the code for my reqiremant@smukov

Comment: What is exactly the problem with your code? Can you add it to your original question?

Comment: Depending on the user the count field should be displayed How?Thats all @Smukov,How to filter the Count fields Depending on the user

Comment: that is my problem i am facing the above code,the count field should be dependent on user how? @smukov

Comment: It will be dependent on the user's Profile, not user. That's what you asked in your original question as far as I understood. If you need it to keep track per user basis, than just change the  `Id profileId = UserInfo.getProfileId()` to `Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId()`, and use the appropriate field on the `View_Count__c` object.

Comment: what is this line does?List<Page_View__c> pageViews = [SELECT Id, Count__c FROM Page_View__c WHERE Profile_Id__c = :profileId ]; Profile_Id__c  this field contains what can you please explain,i want store the count and username in the Record of pageview_c object

Comment: Gets the `View_Count__c` record for a profile of the currently logged in user.

Comment: after getting the Viewcount,how we will find out this profile is belongs to this user

Comment: `UserInfo.getProfileId()` this gives you the ProfileId of the currently logged in user that is viewing your page.

Comment: ok I understand getting the profileid of Currently Logged user and i want to store the username and count in the Record as mentioned as above in my code id ='a0L28000003YzNx' of Page View object record How?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44985/discussion-between-cloud-computing-in-salesforce-and-smukov).

Comment: we will continue in chat